# Redux - what component gets rendered when store state has changed?

Tags: redux

If i'm changing my Redux store's state by dispatching an action, which component would get rendered?

If i have in my code:

ReactDOM.render(, document.getElementById('root'));
Does it mean that App and all of its children components would get re-rendered? Or just the components i'm currently viewing in my browser? (those are the components that are currently mounted on the DOM right?)

Comment: It really depends on how your component tree is set up (PureComponent, shouldComponentUpdate, etc).  But as I understand it, React will run all the render methods for all the components and that will create a virtual dom representation.  That is then diffed with n-1 version.  Finally, the diff changes will create DOM changes.  So, no, the App and all its children will not get re-rendered in the DOM.

Comment: So essentially if, for example, i have a `Main` component that passes state as props to a `Login` component and then the state changes, `Login` will "automatically" get re-rendered since a new updated state has been passed to it by `Main`?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, but re-rendered doesn't mean the entire DOM gets replaced.  Only the minimum required set of DOM changes get applied.

Comment: Ok got it, thanks!

Comment: Please see our new [React-Redux docs page on writing `mapStateToProps` functions](https://react-redux.js.org/docs/using-react-redux/connect-extracting-data-with-mapStateToProps) for a detailed description of when your component will re-render.

Comment: @markerikson would `mapDispatchToProps` also "re-render" components when called? i didn't see that in the document you shared but i think that's the case?

Comment: `mapDispatch` is normally called once when the component instance is created, unless you define the function as needing two parameters ( `(dispatch, ownProps)`).  In that case, it will be re-run every time the wrapper component's props change, and if the output is different than the last time, your component will be re-rendered.